# Calling View of different folder from Asp.net mvc4 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I hava a View Name "Message" in the Jobs folder of Views. And I want to return that view form an action of different controller, named "MarketController"

```
 public class MarketController : Controller
    {

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Save()
        {
          // logic to save the record
            TempData["message"] = "Save successfully";
            return View("Message");   
        }
   }
```

The problem is that the "Message" view is not in the View of Market, how can i return that view from MarketController.
(I do not want to use RedirectToaction method here.)

Comment: Why don't you want to use RedirectToaction ?

Comment: @Paul, I just want to avoid adding an extra action method in JobController.

Comment: @Ish out of interest if the view is used in multiple controllers why not put it in the shared folder.  Then you wont have to use absolute paths.

Comment: @Steve yes this is another good idea.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just use a relative path based on the `Views` folder

```
return View("~/Views/Jobs/Message.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to fill the full address for your Message view ("~/Views/Jobs/Message.cshtml"):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{
    TempData["message"] = "Save successfully";
    return View("~/Views/Jobs/Message.cshtml");
}
```