# Can't change pages .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm trying to switch views from a controller after checking the login info. How can I properly switch to the correct view after running this logic?

I want to switch to the question explanation view. My existing code is below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginBody(LoginModel info)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(info.Email);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(info.Password);

    //Some login Verification Logic

   return View("~\\Views\\QuestionExplanation\\QuestionExplanation");        
}
```

My folders are organized as follows:

[image]

The code for the QuestionExplanationController is as follows:

```
namespace OliviaSite.Controllers
{
    public class QuestionExplanationController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ShowView()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("QuestionExplaination","QuestionExplaination");` Where the first argument stands for the Action and the second for the Controller. If you want to pass an argument see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257632/4625144).

Comment: @DimitarNikovski I get a blank page and when I inspect, I get a 404 error from that. Do you know why that might happen?

Comment: What methods are in your QuestionExplanation controller, and does it exist at all?

Comment: @AdamBrown It exists in my controllers folder along with LoginController (where this logic is happening) 

The only method I have is "ShowView" which just returns the view

Comment: Please post the code of that controller. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamBrown it's now above. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dimitar Nikovski said, you can return `RedirectToAction` from login action to redirect into `ShowView` action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginBody(LoginModel info)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(info.Email);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(info.Password);

    //Some login Verification Logic

   // usage: RedirectToAction("action_name", "controller_name")
   return RedirectToAction("ShowView", "QuestionExplanation");        
}
```

Then, mention target view name in `ShowView` action method (you can use any different view name other than action name, ensure that view name exists in `Views/QuestionExplanation`):

```
// QuestionExplanationController
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ShowView()
{
    return View("QuestionExplanation"); // mention view name here
}
```

The 404 error occurred because view engine tried to find view name supplied by `LoginBody` method which was incorrectly set.

NB: This path seems incorrect:

```
return View("~\\Views\\QuestionExplanation\\QuestionExplanation");
```

The correct relative path should be like this, based on [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335555/calling-view-of-different-folder-from-asp-net-mvc4-controller):

```
return View("~/Views/QuestionExplanation/QuestionExplanation.cshtml");
```